# Anycubic Vyper autoleveling not starting

Tags: calibration, automatic-bed-leveling, anycubic-vyper

Strange problem: I start atoleveling process and see this message:

[image]

I touch nozzle and red lamp is on

[image]

But nothing happens. Since one or two minutes I get message

[image]

How to solve this issue? Anycubic support tells that is cable problem, but I need to wait about two months to get new cable. May be anyone can help?

Thank you.